# hidden article does not stay up on toggle

Tags: jquery, html

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeritter/prsfM/28/

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function howdy(n){
        alert('Howdy '+n+'!');
    }

    function hideArts(){
        $('article').hide();
    }
    hideArts();

    $("a.toggleart").click(function(){
        var cur = $(this).parent().index();
        //alert(cur);
        $('article').eq(cur).toggle();
    });
});
```

Why does the article immediately disappear after toggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `<a>` which sends the user to a new page. You should cancel the `<a>` event by adding a `href="#"` or `onclick="return false;"`

Sending the user to `href=""` will reload the page if you don't cancel it.

Comment: Thanks to the guys below, but Tom caught my error. One of those "Doh!" moments.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjfq7/); I've amended your own with a couple of fixes:

- Your `click` handler needs `e.preventDefault()` to stop the `<a>` navigating to a new page:

  ```
  $("a.toggleart").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  ```
- You don't need to hide your panels using JavaScript. A simple

  ```
  article {
      display: none;
  }
  ```

  Will suffice.

The only thing you *need* to do to fix your problem is add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To your click handler, which stops the browser executing the event's *default* behaviour which is, in this case, navigating to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("a.toggleart").click(function(){
    var cur = $(this).parent().index();
    $('article').eq(cur).toggle();
});
```

to

```
$("a.toggleart").click(function(e){ // added the e as the parameter, it maps to the event
    e.preventDefault(); // this line will cancel the default link action ..
    var cur = $(this).parent().index();
    $('article').eq(cur).toggle();
});
```

To cancel the default functionality of the links...

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/prsfM/29/